# Decimal expansion of 1

Tags: real-numbers

Let $E$ be the set of all x $\in [0,1]$ with decimal expansion containing 0s and 9s. Is E closed? Or more specifically do I consider the limit point 1 being part of set E or not?

Comment: I think either view is permissible. Usually people prefer a terminating form if one is available, but there is no requirement to do so.

Comment: Are you requiring **only** digits 0 and 9? (or only 1 and 9)?

Comment: Sorry that was confusing. I meant digits n and 9, where n is not 0

Comment: I asked that because technically 1 = 1.000000... so the decimal expansion of 1 consists of 0s, ignoring the 1 before the decimal point

Comment: I don't see much point in getting too excited about this in the abstract. The basic rule is that one's math writing should be **clear**. So writing as tersely as possible is usually a mistake. It is better to spell things out in  more detail if there is a risk of confusion.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yes I have seen it. I asked the question because I'm not sure whether the definition of the set is self-contradictory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1=1.000000\ldots=0.999999\ldots$ is not the only problematic value under your definition.  For example

- $\frac1{10}$ can be written $0.100000\ldots$ or $0.099999\ldots$
- $\frac9{10}$ can be written $0.900000\ldots$ or $0.899999\ldots$

and there are many more.

So your definition needs to be clearer about what to do with these cases.

In the case of the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), similar but using digits from $\{0,2\}$ in the ternary base $3$ representation of numbers in $[0,1]$, you can say it has all numbers which *can* be represented with those digits, whether or not there are alternative representations which fail the condition.

If you took the same approach with your $E$ so that most conclusions about the Cantor set also applied to your $E$, then the answer to your question would be "yes" and you would have $\{1,\frac1{10}, \frac9{10}\} \subset E$.  That is your choice

Comment: Though note that $\frac1{11}=0.090909\ldots \in E$ anyway as this is its only decimal representation